# Do sparks fly out of a character in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

When

> Supreme Leader Snoke is killed in The Last Jedi

do sparks fly out of

> him or the chair behind him?

Not going to ask a speculative question as to whether or not someone might in fact be a robot.  But someone if someone who has seen the movie already could sees it again soon could they keep an eye out for that?

Comment: is there a reason to think this happens or is it entirely speculation?

Comment: @nkcampbell I'm sure there were sparks, it's just a matter of whether they came out of him or the chair

Comment: i think it was the chair. time to rewatch it on thursday.

Comment: Could it be ash instead of sparks? Lightsabers are extremely hot and will burn anything they go through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sparks **did fly out of the character**. I found this rather poor-quality clip, which shows enough, however, to prove your observation.

> [image]

Comment: WOAAAHH NEVERMIND, SNOKE IS A ROBOT CONFIRMED!

Comment: Looks like they're embers from the lightsaber burning through his smoking jacket. Good find

Comment: Guys, there are no robots in Star Wars, only droids. ;-)

Comment: You have to think, if he _was_ a droid, General Hux might have commented on it. Unless it was common knowledge of course, in which case it doesn't seem like being chopped in half would necessarily be a death sentence, and you'd expect Hux to suggest reassembling him. I think the lightsaber burning his clothing seems more likely.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Machavity - that looks like glowing ash or embers rather than sparks.